directly integrating data from SurveyToGo with Tableau to create a real-time dashboard
I am Doan Han. I am interested in directly integrating data from SurveyToGo with Tableau to create a real-time dashboard. Are there any options to do it?
Hi everyone. E was assigned a question by my boss about creating a realtime dashboard by linking Tableau with SurveyTogo. I did some research and found out that SurveyTogo does not yet support direct linking with Tableau but must use the API. I wonder if anyone has experience with this, can I ask a few questions?
